# How can I access the data on the variables days and years individually under whatsLeft(self):

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class and simple enter data on the first method. Then I simply add additional methods to interact with them. I am learning Object-Oriented programming :) My problem is that I dont know how to access the values of days and years under the whatsLeft(self): method. I know how to get their values using the return code but not individually.

I always get this error:
  File "./className.py", line 44, in 
    print n.whatsLeft.days()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'days'

```
class dude():

    def getDudeInfo(self, name, age, job, jobDuration):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.job = job
        self.jobDuration = jobDuration

    def getAgeDays(self):
        x = self.age*356
        return x

    def getRetire(self):
        x = 59-self.age
        return x

    def daysByRetire(self):
        x = self.getAgeDays() + self.getRetire()*356
        return x

    def whatsLeft(self):
        days = 35600 - self.daysByRetire()
        years = days / 356
        return "{} or {} years left to live".format(days, years)
```

Comment: `self.days`, `self.years`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused but something similar to this (because of your traceback):

```
class Dude:
    # same as before
    def whatsLeft(self):
        days = 35600 - self.daysByRetire()
        years = days / 356
        return "{} or {} years left to live".format(days, years)

# n = Dude()
print n.whatsLeft.days()
```

You cannot access the `days` and `years` of `whatsLeft` directly outside of the function. You can either change `days` and `years` to instance attribute,

```
class Dude:
    # same as before
    def whatsLeft(self):
        self.days = 35600 - self.daysByRetire()
        self.years = days / 356
        return "{} or {} years left to live".format(self.days, self.years)

# n = Dude()
n.whatsLeft()
print n.days()
```

or return `days` and `years` instead of the string.

```
class Dude:
    # same as before
    def whatsLeft(self):
        days = 35600 - self.daysByRetire()
        years = days / 356
        return days, years

# n = Dude()
print n.whatsLeft()[0]
```

Comment: Did you remember to call it first? `n.whatsLeft()`, and it's good practice to add `self.days = None` and `self.years = None` in `def __init__`

Comment: Sorry but I had missed one of the details in your code. That worked beautifully! Thank you again!!! (beer)